# Method in model which returns another has_many model in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models (I have stripped off unnecessary parts):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :attributes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :name, :value, :is_key
end
```

So basically, a `Product` has many `Category` and a `Category` has many `Attributes`.

What I want is a method inside the `Product` model which will return the attributes which have `:is_key` set to true.

I have tried some variations of

```
  def key_attributes
    Attribute.joins(:category).where(:attributes => {:is_key => true}, :category => {:product_id => self.id}).all
  end
```

but without success.

What should `key_attributes` have inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds you should first do:

```
has_many :attributes, :through => :categories
```

Then it should simply be:

```
joins(:attributes).where(:attributes => { :is_key => true })
```

You could even define an association extension as such:

```
has_many :attributes, :through => :categories do
  def is_key(value=true)
    where(:is_key => value)
  end
end
```